# Saving All Wget Outputs in TextFile (appending)

Tags: php, wget

Right Now I have The Below code , That Gets the contents of the url and store the values as an multiple files in the folder **box** .What i need is I need to store all the outputs of an `$url` in single Text file in appending style.

```
<?php

for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++)
{

$url = "http://www.domain.com/file".$i,".php";
$get = exec("wget -P ./box/ $url > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
echo "done";

}
?>
```

Edit : I need everything in background,so wget is the only option. there are 1000's of url to execute

Comment: [`man wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html).

Answer (score 0):

try [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
$get= file_get_contents("http://www.domain.com/file".$i,".php");
```

then you can parse the content however you want.

Comment: I need everything in background, there are 1000's of url to execute

Comment: Well then you're not making it very clear what you're trying to do. It sounds like you're just trying to dump all the content from a url into a file. PHP might not be the language to use..

Comment: Hmm yea ,,I want to take all the output of all url and dump into an single file